# Jenkins Pipeline job - no stages UI on Job description

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm a noob in Jenkins Pipeline trying to convert a bunch of DSL Flow (Deprecated from Jenkins 2.x) type jobs to Pipeline type Jobs.
as a first step I'm using the Job itself code field to insert my script.
I started with a very basic example but I get a message on the job description that the script doesn't have stages although it does.

> This Pipeline has run successfully, but does not define any stages. Please use the stage step to define some stages in this Pipeline.

the script:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps{
                echo 'mvn install'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

screenshot for reference:
[image]

any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems updating pipeline plugins resolved the issue.